# Can you increase the event parameters every time you click?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, event-handling

I want to add a Select box to select a condition each time I click the add option button.

For example, if you click the button add,

I want the following areas to continue to be added:

[image]

But there's a problem.
That means that the event parameters must be increased every time you click.

Examples include the following functions:

```
test1.html

function Value(){
    google.script.run.addOption(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5);}


test1.gs

function addOption(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5) {
  if(e1 == ‘a’){
     e2+’test’
  else{
     e2 
  }

  if(e3 == ‘b’){
      e3 = e2+’hi’
  }else{
      e3
  }
}
```

It's a matching situation like this way.

value1 => e1

value2 => e2

value3 => e3…

In this situation, the Select box is added every time you click the add option button
If you select 3 more values,

```
 test1.html

 function Value(){

google.script.run.addOption(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8);}


 test1.gs

function addOption(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8) {
//}
```

It should be like this
Is it possible to do this?

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options

1. You pass a single record of some type to your function - say an array. This way, the number of arguments never changes even though you can change the number of elements in the array.
2. Interestingly, JavaScript functions do not check the number of arguments received; thus, you can pass as many arguments to a function as you want and you can access these arguments using the function object's argument property like so

   function myFunction(a) { console.log(arguments[3]); } // prints the fourth argument you passed

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I don't think I understand well. Can you give me a simple example?